# Branch is up-to-date with origin/master but for some reason Git is telling me I have changes to be committed?

Tags: git, github

My local branch is up-to-date with origin/master and I think I was committing and pushing to my github while not in the  within git but it has been sending it to my master branch just fine and it is entirely current with my local files.

For some reason, my git terminal is telling me that I have tons of changes to be committed and not staged changes, etc. yet everything is up-to-date with my master so I have no idea what's going on. My github commits have been going through just fine using git (as can be seen here): https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzX23.png but this is what my git terminal looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfxqE.png

(Sorry if this is unclear, I'm having trouble understanding what's going on so it's hard to explain that well what is going on. Let me know if you need any additional information.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `git fetch` to synchronize your remote branch origin/master with your github branch.

You can also force to synchronize your local copy with your github branch by using `git reset --hard origin/master` (after doing the `git fetch`). Take care: this method will remove every modifications you made not committed.

Comment: I had actually tried that earlier but assumed I was going down the wrong route because I got this error message: http://i.imgur.com/Q1srcSt.png maybe it makes a bit of sense to you? Thanks!

Comment: If you are sure that no other git process is currently running, you can remove the file `.git/index.lock`. This file is created when a git command is run. If you force `git` to stop, sometimes it is not able to delete the file by himself.

Comment: That was the problem, unnecessary lock is what kept me from being able to do it. Removing it worked great, thanks so much! :) Howcome it sometimes randomly creates a lock file? Especially when I was the only one working on it at the time?

Comment: It does not randomly creates a lock file. For example you launch `git pull`: `git` will create a lock file to avoid another `git` process to modify the same data (data inside the `.git` directory), then you do a CTRL+C. Sometimes (due to wrong timing), the process is killed without deleting the lock file (as you kill the process). Thus you have a orphan lock file.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Though I haven't used git pull in months. The only thing I have done is add, commit, and push. Could that in any way cause this lock file? Possibly when pushing?

Comment: In a lot of command the index file is created, like commit, diff, ... (See git source: https://github.com/git/git/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hold_locked_index.)